# Minimal polynomial of endomorphism of permutation module

Tags: group-theory, permutations, representation-theory

Let $G$ be a transitive permutation group on a set $\Omega$. If $n$ is the degree and $M\in\mathbb{Z}^{n\times n}$ is a symmetric matrix that is also contained in $\operatorname{End}_{\mathbb{Q}G}(\mathbb{Q}\Omega)$, then what can be said about the degree of the minimal polynomial $p$ of $M$? I know that $\operatorname{dim}_{\mathbb{Q}}(\operatorname{End}_{\mathbb{Q}G}(\mathbb{Q}\Omega))$ is equal to the rank of $G$. Does $\operatorname{deg}(p)$ also coincide with the rank? Is the symmetry of $M$ relevant?

Comment: But $M$  could be the identity matrix, in which case ${\rm deg}(p)=1$, and it is not hard to find examples with $1 \le {\rm deg}(p) \le {\rm rank}(G)$, but perhaps this inequality always holds.